# "if then statement in VBA to fill cell with number"

Tags: if-statement

"if then statement in VBA" I'm writing a program that puts a number in a cell in Excell if a variable reaches a certain value. I understand how to declare variables but I don't know how to tell excel to write x if A1 =34. Thanks

Comment: How about simply this function in the cell: =IF(A1=34,"x","")

Comment: Thanks David, that could work. I didn't know I had that choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you wish to do, but let's say you want to write the current value of your variable, x, into cell B2... if cell A1 is 34.

In the above case, you would do this:

```
If [a1] = 34 then [b2] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to your worksheet to capture a Range. You can make the range [A1] if you are only watching a specific column/row, or you can add a range like I have below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value = "34" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 2) = "X"
        Else
            Cells(Target.Row, 2) = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Change "x" to if you want variable x and not literal x.

If your goal is to change the value of the cell to "X" (Literal X), and you are not having macros run constantly or with each cell change, you can use the following function (or similar) in each cell in which you have a conditional.

See the Microsoft support on this topic https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213612

Comment: Thanks Brian, the code I want is always listening to a data stream of numbers. When a specific value in the stream appears, the program fills a cell with a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Worksheets("New").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("New").Range("T2").Formula = "=LEFT(B2,2)"
Worksheets("New").Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("New").Range("T2:T" & lr)

Worksheets("New").Range("U2").Formula = "=(T2&0&0)"
Worksheets("New").Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("New").Range("U2:U" & lr)

Worksheets("New").Range("V2").Formula = "=IF(AND(a2=A1,U2=U1),"",A2")"  (HOW TO AUTO FILL THIS FORMULA IN A CELL)
Worksheets("New").Range("V2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("New").Range("V2:V" & lr)

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.