# How do you autofill dates in a column when a date is imported from another sheet by button press weekly?

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a code in VBA to copy weekly comments and the date that the week begins on from one sheet (ws1) to a second one for storage (ws4), auto-populate the remaining dates for the week, and finally add a new line to the bottom of the sheet.

I can get the program to copy the comments and the date from ws1 to ws4. They go into their appropriate columns as they should.
If I press it a second time however, it just overwrites my data and adds a date below the entered date. That's why I figure if I add the dates all the way through, that will solve that issue.
My problem at present is that I can't get the code (I believe should work) to auto-populate my dates. When I get to that line in my code, I am presented with the following error:
"Run-Time Error '1004':
Application-defined or object defined error"
I have looked to try and figure out what it is exactly that is going on and despite my research and hunting, I can't seem to get it to work. I don't know if I'm trying to call out something incorrectly, or if what I'm doing is just not possible.

I considered using an 'If/ Then/ Else' argument to get things to work but I couldn't get it to play nice. The link to the page I looked at to try and figure that out is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374025/if-then-statement-in-vba-to-fill-cell-with-number).
I then thought about that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809881/autofill-a-column-with-month-name-depending-on-the-date-in-another-column-exce) post may provide a bit more insight since it was similar to what I was trying to do regarding entering a month based on another entered date (almost literally my problem). However, this option didn't work for me either. 
Lastly I got to my current solution (which seemed simple and easy to make work). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098031/excel-vba-date-until-last-row) is the link to that original solution with my changed reflected in my provided code.

I'm at a loss as to what is happening and where to go from here. Below you will see my shortened portion of code for this part specifically (it's part of a bigger code that works minus this bit).

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Weekly Job Progress")
Dim ws4 As Worksheet: Set ws4 = Sheets("Comment Storage")
Dim lrow2 As Long: lrow2 = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With ws1 
    'Copy the date to & from.
    ws4.Cells(lrow2, 1) = .Range("E3")
    For m = 7 To 13
        n = m - 4
        'Copy the days of the week
        ws4.Cells(n, 2) = .Range("I" & m)
        'Copy the comments entered
        ws4.Cells(n, 3) = .Range("K" & m)
    Next 
End With

With ws4 
    rowf = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Supposed to automatically populate the dates on ws4 up to the last row... Doesn't work.
    .Range("B:B" & rowf).Value = (rowf - 1)
    'Supposed to add a new row at the bottom of my sheet but doesn't (no clue why because the same code works on ws3 [not shown].)
    .Range("A" & lrow2 + 1).EntireRow.Insert
End With

End Sub
```

If I have done something wrong in my posting of this, please let me know as this is my first time posting to this website though I have used it for my research and learning a good bit in the past couple of weeks.
Thank you.

**Edit 1:** Cleaned up the code and noted it to hopefully make it easier to understand what I'm trying to do and where my problems are. I also made the change that was mentioned in the comments about not using reference with the same letter as a column. Otherwise, my code is unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that ended up working. It took time to get it cleaned up and figured out. However, with some outside help, this works. It ended up being a 2 part code to make it play nice but it solves the issue.

```
With ws1
    'Insert 7 Lines
    ws4.Range("A" & lrow2 + 2).EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(6).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    'Copy the date to & from.
    ws4.Cells(lrow2 + 2, 1) = .Range("E3")
    For m = 7 To 13
        n = m - 4
        'Copy the day of the week.
        ws4.Cells(lrow2 + n - 1, 2) = .Range("I" & m)
        'Copy the comment entered.
        ws4.Cells(lrow2 + n - 1, 3) = .Range("K" & m)
    Next
End With

With ws4
    Dim rowf1 As Long: rowf1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rowf2 As Long: rowf2 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Defines the Destination of cells to AutoFill & the range area to stop at.
    .Range("A" & rowf1).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A" & rowf1 & ":A" & rowf2)
    'To insert a new row at the end of my imported data to give a new line with the same formatting to start on at the next import.
    .Range("B" & rowf2 + 1).EntireRow.Insert
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first with block, try not referecing the range objects onto each other but just the values. Like so: ws4.Cells(m, 3).value = .Range("K" & k).value

Comment: Thank you. I can see where that would be a bigger problem on longer codes with multiple references of it. I will change it since it's a minor change and remember it going forward.

Comment: Just edited my referencing ranges as you suggested (sorry, I should have done that sooner). I also cleaned up my code to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Comment: Your should now get some error with "Rows.Count". This is telling VBA to expect an object variable called rows with an count attribute. I think you need to reference a worksheet's rows attribute. Check out this https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-rows-property-excel

Comment: I will give it a try when I get into the office in a couple of hours. Thank you for that. That may be where part of my problem is at with this if it's not referencing what I think I'm telling it to. I'll also look through the rest of my code in that section to make sure it's cooperating as well.